# android .so files not getting extracted in /data/data/<package>/lib

Tags: android, unsatisfiedlinkerror, android-native-library

I am developing a native android application and using an open source library with .so file generated. Facing a strange behavior.
For the first few times, the application worked perfectly well, with the library getting loaded. But now its not able to find the library and gives -

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load : findLibrary
>   returned null

.Below are few observations: 1. when I extract the .apk file, the library (.so) is present under "lib/armeabi" folder. 2. but when I try to search the library (.so) into the devices extracted path of

> /data/data//lib/
>   , its not present. Any suggestions as to why this strange behavior is happening and why the .so file is not getting extracted under /data/data/com.ibm.homeScreen/lib/ folder.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you use eclipse, check the buildpath settings:
Right click on your project --> Properties --> JavaBuildPath --> Order and Export (is a Tab) and check there if the librar has been marked (checkbox) to export.
There is also a possibility to set the native library path. You can find that option in the Library Tab --> Android Private Libraries --> EDIT Button on the right

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822694/unsatisfiedlinkerror-the-library-loads-but-i-still-get-a-link-error?rq=1) could also help

Comment: This doesn't seem likely to be relevant, especially as the poster says that the .so is present in the apk but not being unpacked on the device.

Answer (score 0):

For eclipse project, simply put all your *.so files inside armeabi or armeabi-v7a folder, and put the folder inside /libs folder in your project. Compile, the *.so files will automatically be imported into /data/data//lib

For Android studio, the above approach didn't work for me. instead I have to place the armeabi and armeabi-v7a folders into /jniLibs instead of /libs. Note that I am using Gradle 0.10.+ though, not sure if it works on older Gradle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find some further information about this problem here:
[Why do some Android phones cause our app to throw an java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111739/why-do-some-android-phones-cause-our-app-to-throw-an-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinker)
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59420

The stackoverflow link also contains some code with a workaround in the (currently) last answer.