# Eclipse plugin project and user library

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I tried to add my own User Library to my eclipse plugin project. But when I run the project, I get the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.
It only works, when I add single jars like mentioned in the accepted answer to this question: [Adding jars to a Eclipse PlugIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744520/adding-jars-to-a-eclipse-plugin)

How do I use custom User Libraries correctly in eclipse plugin projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. Your plug-in executes in the plug-in runtime, which means **all** of its dependencies have to be stated in its manifest or delivered as part of that plug-in. You'll have to place whatever jars make up the user library into the project itself and add them to the runtime section of your manifest.

[image: Runtime tab of Plug-in Manifest Editor]

Don't edit the Java Build Path manually. PDE will change it so that it keeps up with the manifest's contents, but that only goes one-way.

Comment: This means I can not add the whole user library to the project, only single jar by jar?

Comment: Yes.  You need to be **explicit** about these things.

Answer (score 1):

I generally do it by

```
1. Open your plugin.xml
2. Go to Runtime tab and add your JAR in the classpath section
3. Also you have to add the plugin dependencies
```

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/manifest_editor/dependencies.htm